# Carrying Exhibition items From India to Dubai & Back

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, dubai

I am attending an exhibition in Dubai, & i intend to carry the exhibit items with me as check-in baggage.

The items are surgical instruments and none of those items contain Lithium batteries. They are also not under any goods which can be classified as Dangerous goods. The value of the goods is Indian Rupees (INR) 1,00,000 /-

I am exploring the following scenarios with respect to clearing the items at respective customs:

1. Using an ATA Carnet:
   I am filling the Carnet and creating documentation for it, But can i clear it myself as an exporter instead of using a clearance agent? Can the same be done at Dubai Customs?
2. Declaring at Customs section:
   Can I declare the items of such nature at Mumbai Customs, Do i need to pay import duty as checked on cybex.in, which is as follows:

Assessable Value – (A)
(CIF Value + 1% Landing Charge of CIF) (A) 101000.00

Basic Duty – (B) (A) x Basic Duty R ate 10 (B) 10100.00

Preferential Duty – (B)
(A) x Pref. Duty Rate 0 (B) 0.00

CVD: Additional Duty – (C)
(A+B) x CVD Rate 12 (C) 13332.00
Central Excise Edu Cess – (D)
(C) x Central Excise Edu Cess ra te 3 (D) 399.96
Customs Education Cess – (E)
(B+C+D) x Customs Edu. Cess ra te 3 (E) 714.96
Special CVD – Special Duty – (F)
(A+B+C+D+E) x Spl. CVD rate 4 (F) 5021.88

Total Custom Duty (A+B+C+D+E+F) INR 29568.80

Do i need to pay similar Duty during Import into Dubai?

Again the question arises, Can i clear this at the Customs section myself as the exporter of goods